# Opera bug overflow:hidden & position:absolute viewport-size

Tags: html, css, overflow, opera, css-position

I ran into a bug in Opera (v10.63 on Windows7) – not for the first time, but I don't see any workaround this time...

I have a container-div with overflow:hidden. Inside this div a second div (image-holder) with position:absolute and an image. -> The part of the image that exceeds the dimensions of the container should be hidden (I don't want this image to affect scrollbars)

What Opera gets wrong is the size of the viewport:
Instead of using the size of the container to calculate the size of the viewport, Opera calculates it using the size of the image-holder (-> I get scrollbars).

—

Here's the link to my site (image in the bottom-left corner):
http://lescaves.ch

I found following article reporting the bug (but not providing any solution):
http://www.greywyvern.com/code/opera/bugs/OverflowPositioning

—

Does anyone have any experience with this or knows a fix/workaround?

Thanks,
Julian

Comment: i have the same version but there is no scroll as far as i can see

one thing to do

Comment: hmm... that's strange... Is the whole image being displayed (the illustration with the two persons drinking) ?

Comment: here's an image of what I'm seeing: http://bit.ly/gLKnRR

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `position: fixed` to the `<img>` tag (not the #image selector).

Comment: Doesn't work... The image stays fixed to the bottom of the viewport (not the desired effect). Thanks for your answer.